# Change RGB values of a JPEG or PNG Image from C using jpeglib.h

Tags: c, image, rgb

First of all I've never worked with images on C, so I'm searching for a way in which I can change the RGB values of a JPEG or PNG image to get a red, blue and green result image, just like a color filter would do by changing the R values to 0, G to 0 and B to 255 and vice versa, but I need to do it in C, I'm using jpeglib.h and a reference code for guidance, as I've never worked with this API before, I can load an image and write it as an output image, however I haven't found anywhere a way to change the RGB values, how can I do it?

I'm working on a UNIX environment, and I'm trying to learn how to process any jpeg image to a ppm format due to academic reasons.

my code is the following:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rc, i, j;
  char *syslog_prefix = (char*) malloc(1024);
  sprintf(syslog_prefix, "%s", argv[0]);
  openlog(syslog_prefix, LOG_PERROR | LOG_PID, LOG_USER);

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s filename.jpg\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  struct stat file_info;
  unsigned long jpg_size;
  unsigned char *jpg_buffer;
  struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
  struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
  unsigned long bmp_size;
  unsigned char *bmp_buffer;
  int row_stride, width, height, pixel_size;

  rc = stat(argv[1], &file_info);
  if (rc) {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "FAILED to stat source jpg");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  jpg_size = file_info.st_size;
  jpg_buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(jpg_size + 100);

  int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  i = 0;
  while (i < jpg_size) {
    rc = read(fd, jpg_buffer + i, jpg_size - i);
    i += rc;
  }
  close(fd);

  cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);  
  jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
  jpeg_mem_src(&cinfo, jpg_buffer, jpg_size);

  rc = jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);

  if (rc != 1) {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "File does not seem to be a normal JPEG");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);

  width = cinfo.output_width;
  height = cinfo.output_height;
  pixel_size = cinfo.output_components;

  bmp_size = width * height * pixel_size;
  bmp_buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(bmp_size);

  row_stride = width * pixel_size;

  while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height) {
    unsigned char *buffer_array[1];
    buffer_array[0] = bmp_buffer + \
               (cinfo.output_scanline) * row_stride;

    jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, buffer_array, 1);

  }

  jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);

  jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);

  free(jpg_buffer);

  fd = open("output.ppm", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0666);
  char buf[1024];

  rc = sprintf(buf, "P6 %d %d 255\n", width, height);
  write(fd, buf, rc);
  write(fd, bmp_buffer, bmp_size);

  close(fd);
  free(bmp_buffer);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please show the program which reads in a picture and writes it unchanged to the three color channel picutes. I.e. show your code frame context, with input and output. Then you might get help with itnerpreting pictures formats. As it is, the question is to broad, or asking for a tutorial or asking for a tool; all three readings are off-topic.

Comment: Please don't post half your code - you presumably need some header files #included so show that part too. Also show how you compile it and say what platform you are on - Windows? Linux? Is your goal to learn some programming of image processing, or is there something specific you are trying to do? Why do you think you want to output a PPM file?

Answer (score 0):

I think  that  the better way to that is by  decompress the image change the colors,  you want to  change and save it's again ,  I do the first part, but I don't know how to put data in the new image again, in your case there In the next step, you need to convert to ppm.  it's the path to save an image that  is in the correct format,  but I don't know how to put the image in this format. https://www.huinfinito.com.br/motores/1438-valvula-solenoide-para-agua-12v-180-x-.html, if you discovered how to do that , replie  this   post.  to change the rgb value you can  change directly from their addres since it's a conjunct of integer.

```
if(i2==3||(sair==1&&i2==2)){         
 contCorSelecionada++;
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
 *datamenos3=corTroca.limiteinferior[i];
 datamenos3++;`}
```

i do that but fallen in  the problem that i mentioned before.